# How do I fix my Cocos2d-x project in visual Studios from taking a long time to load

Tags: c++, coco2d-x

[Image of the load screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkrtN.png)

I am making a game in Cocos2d-x using Visual Studios 2015, it complies quickly, but then freezes on the below image.
Why does it compile quickly but then takes a long time to actually load up?

Comment: How can we answer without the code!

Comment: Because you are loading a lot of data from disk at startup? There are literally a million possible reasons why this could happen and you really gave no information. Try making a simple scene on Cocos2D and test that. If it is still slow, then buy a faster computer.